# how to get drop-down menu with checkbox using html only?

Tags: html, css

this will give me drop-down menu

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i want to have each value of drop-down menu with checkbox so i can select multiple value and can submit it together.
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXzfs.png)

Comment: Are you just looking for [the `multiple` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple)?

Comment: i want to select(check) multiple checkbox from drop-down and than submit them

Comment: Then yes, you are looking for the `multiple` attribute for your `<select>`.  *Edit:* You've edited your comment to include "checkboxes".  If you want a *custom* multi-select UX then you'd need to build that or use a third party tool.  The native HTML `<select>` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [select's multiple attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp), should be what you're looking for.